# Download iTunes App Ratings - NOT just reviews, Ratings given with or without review

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I can download the reviews for any app using the following URL:

> https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=12345678/sortBy=mostRecent/json?l=en

However it only gives the app ***reviews*** but not all the ***ratings***.

The two are different as iTunes app store users can rate an App without leaving a review.
When you view "Ratings & Reviews" in ITC you get all the ratings for any version.

Is there a way the ratings can be downloaded either using the rss feed url above or *reportingitc.apple.com/autoingestion* ?